# Using Resolve In AngularJS Routes not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

A resolve is a property you can attach to a route in both ngRoute and the more robust UI router.but resolve can not working well. not load data

```
.factory("Init", function($cordovaContacts) {
    var contacts = []; //variable that holds contacts, returned from getContacts
    return {
        getContacts: function() {
            var options = {};
            options.filter = "";
            options.multiple = true;

            //get the phone contacts
            $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function(result) {
                contacts = result;
            }, function(err) {});
            return contacts;
        }
    }
})
```

Routes

```
 .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController',
                resolve: {
                    getContacts: function(Init) {
                        return Init.getContacts();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Controller.js

`app.controller("homeController", function (message) {
     $scope.greeting = getContacts;
        console.log($scope.greeting);
});`

Comment: can you tell me, why are you injecting message as dependency in controller??

Comment: i write like this. app.controller("homeController", function ( $scope,Init,message) { $scope.greeting = Init.getContacts; console.log($scope.greeting)

Answer (score 0):

`$cordovaContacts.find(options)` is a async call and it already returning a promise. So, you can return it directly in your method - `resolve` method can handle the promise and return the result. In your code you are returning `contacts` before the call get finished.

```
.factory("Init", function($cordovaContacts) {
    var contacts = []; //variable that holds contacts, returned from getContacts
    return {
        getContacts: function() {
            var options = {};
            options.filter = "";
            options.multiple = true;

            //get the phone contacts
            return $cordovaContacts.find(options);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: i write like this.
app.controller("homeController", function ( $scope,Init,message) {
    $scope.greeting = Init.getContacts;
        console.log($scope.greeting);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki. You need to inject your getContacts key defined in resolve to your controller.